# How many $n$-letter words formed from $k=3$ letter classes have an even number of $a$s?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be letters of an alphabet. How many words of $n$ letters contain an even number of a?

So I tried to do this like this:

Lets assume 'a' is the first letter. If 'a' is also the second letter we have $d_{n-2}$ words(I call the sequence d so I won't make any mistake with the letters a,b,c). If the second letter is 'b' or 'c' we have $3^{n-2}-d_{n-2}$ words, then we just need to multiply by 2 because the 2 options are symmetric.

Now lets assume the first letter is either 'b' or 'c'. There are $d_{n-1}$ words. we multiply by 2 becasue the 2 options are symmetric.

In total we got:

$d_n = 2d_{n-1}+d_{n-2}+2\cdot(3^{n-2}-d_{n-2})=2d_{n-1}+2\cdot3^{n-2}-d_{n-2}$

The goal is to find a solution without using $\sum$.

So I tried using generating functions and got:

$f(x)=2x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (3x)^n\sum_{n=0}^\infty (2x)^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (2x)^n$

Is there any way to continue from here?Am I missing something?

Comment: If $E_n$ is the number of words of length $n$with an even number of $a's$, and $O_n$ the number with an odd number of $a's$, then $3^n=E_n+O_n$ and $E_n=O_{n-1}+2E_{n-1}=3^{n-1}+E_{n-1}$.

Comment: Looking at the second letter is unnecessary because we don't care whether or not we have two a's next to each other. Just look at the first letter.

Comment: also $E_1 = d_1 = 0$ and $E_2 = d_2 = 1$, so we now have a linear 2nd order difference equation with initial values.

Comment: but 0 is even so $E_1=2,E_0=1$

Answer (score 1):

Look at the first letter only. A string with an even number of a's starts with either:

- 'a', followed by a string with an odd number of a's
- 'b' or 'c' followed by a string with an even number of a's

Let $E_n$ be the number of strings of length $n$ with an even number of a's and $O_n$ the same but with an odd number of a's.

As lulu points out in the comments,

$$ E_n + O_n = 3^n $$

and

$$ E_n = O_{n - 1} + 2E_{n - 1} = 3^{n - 1} + E_{n - 1}$$

Now multiply both sides by $x^{n}$ and sum to get

$$ \Phi(x) = 1 + \frac{x}{1 - 3x} + x\Phi(x) $$

where $\Phi(x)$ is the generating function for $E_n$.

Hence

$$ \Phi(x) = \frac{1 - 2x}{(1 - 3x)(1 - x)}. $$

Therefore

$$ E_n = \frac{3^n + 1}{2}. $$

Comment: Initially I had the equation $\Psi(x) = 0 + \frac{x}{1 - 3x} + x\Psi(x)$ which would be correct if $E_0 = 0$ but $E_0 = 1$. Since $O_0 = 0$ this $\Psi$ is actually the generating function for $O_n$, not $E_n$. One can check that $\Psi(x) = \frac{x}{(1 - 3x)(1 - x)}$ and hence $\Phi(x) + \Psi(x) = \frac{1}{1 - 3x}$ as we expect.

Answer (score 1):

Using exponential generating functions,

$\displaystyle g_e(x)=\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots\right)\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots\right)\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots\right)$

$\displaystyle\hspace{.4 in}=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}\cdot e^x\cdot e^x=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{3x}+e^x\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{3^n+1}{2}\cdot\frac{x^n}{n!},\;\;$ so $\;\displaystyle d_n=\frac{3^n+1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider exactly 2 $a$'s:

There are

${n \choose 2}$ ways to choose the two positions for the $a$s, and $2^{n-2}$ possible ways to fill the remaining $n-2$ slots with either a $b$ or a $c$, the total being ${n \choose 2} 2^{n-2}$.

Likewise for exactly 4 $a$s:

${n \choose 4}$

and

$2^{n-4}$,

giving ${n \choose 4} 2^{n-4}$.

And likewise for all even number of $a$s.  How many such terms are there?  $k = \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$.

So sum these up:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} {n \choose 2 i} 2^{n-2 i}$.

Comment: The whole point was to do this without a $\sum$

Comment: I suppose so... but the OP's solution had summations throughout, so I thought it acceptable.  (I guess not, though.)

Comment: The sum $\sum_k \binom{n}{2k}x^{2k}$ is the even bisection of $(1 + x)^n$ so that's $\frac12((1 + x)^n + (1 - x)^n)$. Hence $$ \sum_k \binom{n}{2k}x^{n - 2k} = x^n \frac12 \left( \left( 1 + \frac1x \right)^n + \left(1 -\frac1x \right)^n \right) = \frac12 \left( \left( x + 1 \right)^n + \left(x - 1 \right)^n \right). $$

Comment: well... I wrote the comment as OP lol. Look at the sums I wrote, they are sums of generating functions, not sums in the solution